# Android NDK fails to compile Telegram project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, telegram

Android NDK compile fails at

```
[arm64-v8a] Install        : libtmessages.29.so => libs/arm64-v8a/libtmessages.29.so
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libtmessages.29.so
jni/./ffmpeg/armv7-a/libavutil.a(mem.o): In function `av_malloc':
mem.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `posix_memalign'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libtmessages.29.so] Error 1
```

Can anybody suggest me what's wrong with it. 
I am using Android Studio 3.1.4.
NDK: android-ndk-r17c
Using Windows 7 32bit.

This happens while compiling on fresh download of Telegram source code from 
git clone — recursive https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram.git

First I thought this might be because of NDK, I tried with ndk-r16b with same error while ndk-r14b and r15b return

```
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/Android.mk:avutil: The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt library should only contain one item
G:/Softwares/android-ndk-r15c/build//../build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:28: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

If anybody has gone through this, please mention here what is the cause behind this and how we can do it.

Comment: As far as I know, `posix_memalign` is available for `APP_PLATFORM` >= 16. Your `Application.mk` sets `APP_PLATFORM := 14`. I suggest you raise it to 16 or higher (unless your `minSdkVersion` really is 14, in which case you may be out of luck).

Comment: You might be better off trying to find something more up to date (or write it yourself). That project uses GCC and the GNUStl, both of which are deprecated in the NDK.

Answer (score 1):

Use ndk r16b.

Works fine with the latest changes at [a724d96e](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/commit/a724d96e9c008b609fe188d122aa2922e40de5fc)

Found the answer here:
https://github.com/grishka/libtgvoip/issues/8#issuecomment-417647322